# Nhibernate Fluent on C#, could not execute query for entity with datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I've a strange problem with Fluent Nhibernate on C#.
Here you can see my entity, my map, and my repository. The problem is when i try to get a entity from the db. 
if I use only CODE_B or CODE_C the query will fail with "Could not load entity", but if I use CODE_A before CODE_B or CODE_C everything is working fine. 
If I delete :

```
Map(x => x.MODI_DAT);
Map(x => x.MODI_ORA);
```

all is working fine.
I've tried to use these fields with string, datetime and to force customSqlType "datetime" but no one is working.
I don't understand why if I get all entities from table the query for id is working, but if i don't ask before all the list i get an error.

The other strange thing is that when i get the error, exception shows me the query of the object one. If I manually try the query on db I correctly get the result object.

Repository:

```
namespace WebApplication.Providers
{
    public class TTW_SA_DETRepository
    {

        public TTW_SA_DET get() {
            //var all = session.QueryOver<TTW_SA_DET>().List();   CODE_A
            //var one = session.Get<TTW_SA_DET>( new TTW_SA_DET { 
CODI_SOC = "$$$", SAD_NOME_FORM = "ANAG_AZIONI", SAD_ORDE_COL = 0 });   CODE_B 
            var one = session.QueryOver<TTW_SA_DET>()
                .Where(x => x.CODI_SOC == "$$$")
                .And(x => x.SAD_NOME_FORM == "ANAG_AZIONI")
                .And(x => x.SAD_ORDE_COL == 0)
                .SingleOrDefault<TTW_SA_DET>();  // CODE_C
            return one;
        }



         protected NHibernate.ISessionFactory sessionFactory;
         protected NHibernate.ISession session;


         protected NHibernate.ISession openSession()
         {
              sessionFactory =          
    MicrosoftSQLConfNhibernate.CreateSessionFactory();
              session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

              return session;
        }

        public TTW_SA_DETRepository()
        {
            openSession();
        }

    }
```

inside my main (Startup.cs):

```
var rep = new TTW_SA_DETRepository();
rep.get();
```

Entity:

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class TTW_SA_DET
    {
        virtual public string CODI_SOC { get; set; }
        virtual public string SAD_NOME_FORM { get; set; }
        virtual public int SAD_ORDE_COL { get; set; }
        virtual public DateTime MODI_DAT { get; set; }
        virtual public DateTime MODI_ORA { get; set; }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var val = obj as TTW_SA_DET;
            return val != null &&
                   CODI_SOC == val.CODI_SOC &&
                   SAD_NOME_FORM == val.SAD_NOME_FORM &&
                   SAD_ORDE_COL == val.SAD_ORDE_COL;                   
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            var hashCode = 1411657508;
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(CODI_SOC);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(SAD_NOME_FORM);
            hashCode = hashCode * -1521134295 + EqualityComparer<int>.Default.GetHashCode(SAD_ORDE_COL);
            return hashCode;
        }

    }
}
```

EntityMap:

```
namespace WebApplication.Models
{
    public class TTW_SA_DETMap : ClassMap<TTW_SA_DET>
    {
        public TTW_SA_DETMap()
        {
            Table("TTW_SA_DET");
            CompositeId()
                .KeyProperty(x => x.CODI_SOC)
                .KeyProperty(x => x.SAD_NOME_FORM)
                .KeyProperty(x => x.SAD_ORDE_COL);
            Map(x => x.MODI_DAT);//.CustomSqlType("datetime");
            Map(x => x.MODI_ORA);//.CustomSqlType("datetime");
        }

    }
}
```

DB config:

```
namespace WebApplication
{
    public class MicrosoftSQLConfNhibernate
    {


        public static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
        {
            return Fluently.Configure()
       .Database(MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2012.ConnectionString(c => c
                .Server("myCORRECTdata")
                .Database("myCORRECTdata")
                .Username("myCORRECTdata")
                .Password("myCORRECTdata")
                ).ShowSql()
              )
              .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Startup>())
              .BuildSessionFactory();
        }

    }
}
```

Finally this is the table on MSSQL 2014:

```
CREATE TABLE EDILWEB_MONET.dbo.TTW_SA_DET (
    CODI_SOC varchar(3) NOT NULL,
    SAD_NOME_FORM varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    SAD_ORDE_COL int NOT NULL,
    MODI_DAT datetime,
    MODI_ORA datetime,
    CONSTRAINT PK_SY_SA_DET PRIMARY KEY (CODI_SOC,SAD_NOME_FORM,SAD_ORDE_COL)
) go
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably is a network problem, with another gateway the code is working. Maybe the problem is a firewall somewhere or a MTU bad configuration.